# Webscrape using BS4 but text has same p class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the ingredient list from products on
https://www.mecca.com/en-au/skincare/

The URL element in the first product for example (https://www.mecca.com/en-au/drunk-elephant/lala-retro-whipped-cream-V-038949/?cgpath=skincare) is:

```html
<div role="region" title="Ingredients" id="sect5e670152-13f8-46ca-9f0b-4c60b533d079" aria-labelledby="accordion-5e670152-13f8-46ca-9f0b-4c60b533d079" aria-controls="accordion-5e670152-13f8-46ca-9f0b-4c60b533d079-container" class="css-1g2bsc4">
  <div>
    <p class="css-pdiqc3 e151354a4">Water/aqua/eau, glycerin, caprylic/capric triglyceride, isopropyl isostearate, pseudozyma epicola/camellia sinensis seed oil/glucose/glycine soja (soybean) meal/malt extract/yeast extract ferment filtrate, glyceryl stearate se, cetearyl alcohol, palmitic acid, stearic acid, pentylene glycol, plantago lanceolata leaf extract, adansonia digitata seed oil, citrullus lanatus (watermelon) seed oil, passiï¬‚ora edulis seed oil, schinziophyton rautanenii kernel oil, sclerocarya birrea seed oil, polyglyceryl6 ximenia americana seedate, cholesterol, ceramide ap, ceramide eop, sodium hyaluronate crosspolymer, ceramide np, phytosphingosine, ceteareth20, trisodium ethylenediamine disuccinate, tocopherol, sodium lauroyl lactylate, sodium hydroxide, citric acid, carbomer, xanthan gum, caprylyl glycol, chlorphenesin, phenoxyethanol, ethylhexylglycerin.</p></div></div>
```

I would like to get the Ingredient list, i.e. the Water/aqua/eau...

Below is my code, unfortunately there are several tags on the page with the same <p class="css-pdiqc3 e151354a4"

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mecca.com"

productlinks = []

for x in range(1,5):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://www.mecca.com/en-au/skincare/?page={x}').content, "html.parser")
    products = soup.find_all('div', class_="css-1r7iqog")

    for item in products:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlinks.append(url + link['href'])
    
for link in productlinks:
    response = requests.get(link)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    brand = soup.find("span", class_="product-brand css-738lkl e11u5ot719").string
    name = soup.find('span', class_='product-name css-x4jxi0 e11u5ot718').string
    **Ingred = soup.find('p', class_='css-pdiqc3 e151354a4')** 
    


    print(brand)
    print(name)
    print(Ingred)
```

I was reading through the other posts and have tried some of the other solutions suggested such as:

```html
Ingred = soup.find_all('p', class_='css-pdiqc3 e151354a4')[8].get_text()

or 

Details = soup.find_all('Ingredients', {'class':'css-1g2bsc4'})
Ingred = BeautifulSoup(str(Details).strip()).get_text()
```

but I can't seem to get it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mecca.com/en-au/drunk-elephant/lala-retro-whipped-cream-V-038949/?cgpath=skincare"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

title = soup.h1.text
print(title)
print("-" * 80)

all_p = soup.select('h3:-soup-contains("ingredients") ~ p')
for p in all_p:
    ingr, desc = p.text.split(":")
    print(f"{ingr:<40} {desc:<60}")
```

Prints:

```
Drunk Elephant Lala Retro™ Whipped Cream
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plantain extract                          promotes skin firmness and elasticity whilst evening skin tone.
Fermented green tea seed                  fights ageing, inflammation and protects against environmental aggressors.
Sodium hyaluronate crosspolymer           smooths fine lines and wrinkles whilst stimulating collagen production.
```

---

EDIT: The `ingredients` section is embedded inside `<script>` element, so to parse it, use `json` module:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mecca.com/en-au/drunk-elephant/lala-retro-whipped-cream-V-038949/?cgpath=skincare"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

title = soup.h1.text
print(title)
print("-" * 80)

data = soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").text
data = json.loads(data)

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

ingredients = data["props"]["pageProps"]["pdpContent"]["ingredients"][0]
print(ingredients)
```

Prints:

```
Drunk Elephant Lala Retro™ Whipped Cream
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Water/aqua/eau, glycerin, caprylic/capric triglyceride, isopropyl isostearate, pseudozyma epicola/camellia sinensis seed oil/glucose/glycine soja (soybean) meal/malt extract/yeast extract ferment filtrate, glyceryl stearate se, cetearyl alcohol, palmitic acid, stearic acid, pentylene glycol, plantago lanceolata leaf extract, adansonia digitata seed oil, citrullus lanatus (watermelon) seed oil, passiï¬‚ora edulis seed oil, schinziophyton rautanenii kernel oil, sclerocarya birrea seed oil, polyglyceryl6 ximenia americana seedate, cholesterol, ceramide ap, ceramide eop, sodium hyaluronate crosspolymer, ceramide np, phytosphingosine, ceteareth20, trisodium ethylenediamine disuccinate, tocopherol, sodium lauroyl lactylate, sodium hydroxide, citric acid, carbomer, xanthan gum, caprylyl glycol, chlorphenesin, phenoxyethanol, ethylhexylglycerin.
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thank you so much for your advice
Your code for printing the title is so much more efficient

Comment: For the ingredients I was hoping to extract the "ingredient list" (ie water/aqua/eau, glycerin etc) rather than "key ingredients"
Would you have a solution to this?
I will try to work on your suggestion in the meantime to get this and post if I'm successful!

Comment: thank you so much, i'm not familiar with json so this is certainly something I'll have to learn